# Counting integer points in Taxicab balls

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, normed-spaces

Consider the [Taxicab norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) of a vector $n=(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^k$:

$$||n||_1 = \sum_{i=1}^k |n_i|$$

The volume of the ball of radius $m\in\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is the number of points $n$ with $||n||_1 \leq m$ and is given by

$$V^{(k)}_m = (2\,m - 1)^k - 2^k\,\binom{m-2 + k -1}{k} + 2\,k$$

It is the number of points in the $k$-dimensional cube of side length $2\,m - 1$ minus $2^k$ times the $k$-dimensional [tetraedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatope_number) $T^{(k)}_{m-2}$  (one for each vertex of the cube) plus $2\,k$ (one for each face of the cube).

The integer surface area of the ball is the number $A^{(k)}_m$ of integer points with $||n||_1 = m$ and is given by $V^{(k)}_m - V^{(k)}_{m-1}$.

For $k=2$ we get

$$V^{(2)}_m = m^2 + (m+1)^2$$

and $A^{(2)}_m = 4\,m$.

For $k=3$ we get

$$V^{(3)}_m = \frac{1}{3}\big(20\, (m - \frac{2}{5})^3 + \frac{2}{5}\, (m - \frac{2}{5}) + \frac{411}{25}\big)$$.

It's fun to see how it turns out that [$V^{(3)}_1 = 7, V^{(3)}_2 = 33, V^{(3)}_3 = 123$](https://oeis.org/A000328).

My main question is:

> **Which simplified polynomial form can be given for $V^{(k)}_m$ and/or $A^{(k)}_m$ for $k > 3$?**

Even though the background of my question is in graph theory (I am looking for the number of nodes at graph distance $m$ in a $k$-dimensional cubic grid) I also have the following questions:

- What's the generating function of $A^{(k)}_m$?
- What's the (asymptotic) relation of $V^{(k)}_m$ and the number $N^{(k)}_m$ of points of norm $||n||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2} \leq m$ ([Gauss' circle problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html)) for $k, m \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: The form of $V_m^{(k)}$ looks pretty simple already, I don't see how it can be simplified. Asymptotically, for $m$ fixed and $k\to\infty$, it looks to me like the $(2m-1)^k$ term dominates the others.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: It's surely the $m^k$ term that dominates, but by which factor $c_k$? For $k=2$ we have $c_2=2$, for $k=3$ we have $c_3=20/3$. What is the general form and maybe the limit for $k\rightarrow \infty$ of $c_k$?

Comment: It looks like $(2m-1)^k+2^kP_m(k)$ where $P_m$ is a polynomial in $k$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I would say $P_m(k) = \binom{m+k-3}{k}$ is a polynomial in $m$.

Comment: Depends on your point of view. I wouldn't argue with you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The leading term of $\binom{m+k-3}{k}$ is $ m^k/k!$ and so the leading term of $V_m^{(k)}$ is $a_k\, m^k$ with $a_k = 2^k\,(1 - 1/k!)$ which gives $a_2 = 2$ and $a_3 = 20/3$. For $k \rightarrow \infty$ we have $a_k \approx 2^k$.